# Appending to a text file with DOS system calls

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86, dos, x86-16

Good day! I have here a TASM code and it does not append the new string when I run the program again. What are the lines of code for appending? Thank you very much!

```
; This example program creates a file and then writes to it.
.model small
.stack

.data 
CR equ 13
LF equ 10

StartMessage DB "This program creates a file called NEW.TXT"
         DB ,"on the C drive.$"

EndMessage DB CR,LF,"File create OK, look at file to"
       DB ,"be sure.$"

WriteMessage  DB "An error has occurred (WRITING)$"
OpenMessage   DB "An error has occurred (OPENING)$"
CreateMessage DB "An error has occurred (CREATING)$"

WriteMe  DB "HELLO, THIS IS A TEST, HAS IT WORKED?",0
FileName DB "new.txt",0 ; name of file to open 
Handle   DW ?   ; to store file handle 

.code 
START:
mov ax,@data    ; base address of data segment
mov ds,ax   ; put it in ds
mov dx,offset StartMessage 
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 

mov dx,offset FileName  ; put offset of filename in dx 
xor cx,cx       ; clear cx - make ordinary file
mov ah,3Ch      ; function 3Ch - create a file
int 21h         ; call DOS service

jc CreateError      ; jump if there is an error

mov dx,offset FileName  ; put offset of filename in dx
mov al,2        ; access mode -read and write
mov ah,3Dh      ; function 3Dh - open the file
int 21h         ; call dos service

jc OpenError        ; jump if there is an error
mov Handle,ax       ; save value of handle 

mov dx,offset WriteMe   ; address of information to write 
mov bx,Handle       ; file handle for file
mov cx,38       ; 38 bytes to be written
mov ah,40h      ; function 40h - write to file
int 21h         ; call dos service

jc WriteError       ; jump if there is an error
cmp ax,cx       ; was all the data written?
jne WriteError      ; no it wasn't - error!

mov bx,Handle       ; put file handle in bx 
mov ah,3Eh      ; function 3Eh - close a file
int 21h         ; call dos service

mov dx,offset EndMessage 
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 

ReturnToDOS:

mov ax,4C00h        ; terminate program 
int 21h 

WriteError:
mov dx,offset WriteMessage 
jmp EndError

OpenError:
mov dx,offset OpenMessage 
jmp EndError

CreateError:
mov dx,offset CreateMessage 

EndError:
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 
mov ax,4C01h 
int 21h 

END START
```

Also, does the program need to be terminated before the string can be put into the file? Thank you very much!

**EDIT**
@us2012: Following your answer, should I replace

```
mov bx,Handle       ; file handle for file
mov cx,38       ; 38 bytes to be written
mov ah,40h      ; function 40h - write to file
int 21h         ; call dos service
```

with

```
mov dx,offset WriteMe   ; address of information to write 
mov bx,Handle       ; file handle for file
mov cx,38       ; 38 bytes to be written
;xor dx, dx
mov ah,40h      ; function 40h - write to file
mov al, 02h
int 21h         ; call dos service
```

? It still doesn't append when I run the program again. Still a single `HELLO, THIS IS A TEST, HAS IT WORKED?`.

Answer (score 1):

int21h reference says that to move the file pointer, you'd use function `42h`. Details are  [here](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-42.html), so the following should work for seeking to the end of the file before writing:

```
mov bx, Handle
xor cx, cx
xor dx, dx
mov ah, 42h
mov al, 02h
int 21h
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it still doesn't append. Please see the edit in my question.

Comment: @Aeolus No, you shouldn't *replace* anything, you should *add* this after opening the file, but before writing to it. The edit you made to your question makes no sense at all, it doesn't even have a call with `ah` being `42h`.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I placed your code before `mov dx,offset WriteMe` but nothing happens. Also tried it before and after `jc OpenError ` but it still doesn't append.

Comment: Well... it can't work because you create the file again every time your program runs. Creating via `3c` truncates an existing file to zero bytes. Use `6c` for creating/opening instead: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-6c.html

Comment: I replaced `mov ah,3Ch` with `mov ah,6Ch` now and placed your code before `mov dx,offset WriteMe` but new.txt is not created anymore. What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: You have to read the documentation for `int 42h / 6Ch` and figure out how to set the registers correctly, the link is in my last comment. You'll have to set BX, CX, DX and AL.

Answer (score -4):

```
.data
filename db 'myfile.txt',0
handler dw ?
msg db "hello$"
buffer db 1000 dup (?)
writeme db "world$"
.code
;;;;;;;;;;APPENDING
    append proc
        mov dx,offset writeme
        mov bx,handler
        mov cx,5  ;length of appended string
        mov ah,42h
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h
    append endp
end
```

Comment: int 21h/ah=09 just writes a string to stdout.  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09 You'd have to run that with stdout already redirected (in append mode) to your file.  It takes a `$`-terminated string, not a length in CX.  Did you maybe forget to do a system call with `AH=42h` before overwriting it with `09h`?  Because that first `mov` to AH is useless; nothing uses that value before it's overwritten.