# Writing to a file in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, dos

I need to write data to a txt file in assembly, without erasing the current data (that is, to *add* data, not to replace it). Right now whenever I write I replace everything currently in the file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
writeFile Proc  
            push ax bx cx dx

            ;open file
            mov dx, offset fileName
            mov cx, 0
            mov ah,3ch
            int 21h
            mov filePointer, ax

            ;write to file
            mov dx, offset dataToWrite ;data
            mov cx, DATA_TO_WRITE_LEN  ;size of data
            mov bx, filePointer
            mov ah, 40h
            int 21h

            ;close file
            mov bx, filePointer
            mov ah, 3eh
            int 21h 
            pop dx cx bx ax
            ret
writeFile endp
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling

```
        mov ah,3ch
        int 21h
```

Ie, *create* a file.  If you use this call on an existing file that file will be truncated.  You should use

```
        mov ah,3dh
        int 21h
```

with the [appropriate flags in AL](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3d.html) to *open* the file.

Comment: now nothing is written in the file.. I thought that 3dh was used when reading a file, not editing it?

Comment: No, it opens the file, but it can be opened for read, write or both - check the value you store in AL, you can follow the link I have in my reply for an overview of what values you can use there.  You will need to add a call to function 42 (move file pointer) if you want to append something to the file.

Comment: Actually, probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721746/appending-to-a-text-file-in-assembly